# How to get informal synonyms (ie technology => tech)?

Tags: ruby, nlp

How can I get informal synonyms or abbreviations for a word? I tried using stemmers (like the Porter filter) and thesauruses, but they don't seem to recognize "informal" synonyms for a word. I guess my examples below are not really synonyms, but rather abbreviations.

Examples include:

1. Technology => Tech
2. Business => Biz
3. Applications => Apps

Comment: You might want to ask about the origin of the words on http://english.stackexchange.com. Someone there might have ideas on software or tools that would help too. Apple's dictionary says the first two are abbreviations, "Tech" from the 20th century, and "Biz" from the 19th. "Apps" is the plural of "app" which is an informal word for applications. An online dictionary might help too.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no such library available. The synonyms/abbreviations you mention in the question are a part of the evolutionary nature of any natural language. That is to say, hard-coding such a list will never ever give you a complete list of such equivalences.

The only good long (or even medium) term solution is to use appropriate NLP/ML paradigms to "learn" them. Such equivalences are highly context dependent. For example:

- NLP == *natural language processing* OR *neuro-linguistic programming* (ambiguous acronym)
- Ft. == *foot* OR *featuring* (ambiguous abbreviation)

A historical (and slightly philosophical) presentation of this context dependence is explained [here](http://www.textcreationpartnership.org/docs/dox/ambigs.html). For a more day-to-day example, see [this Wikipedia disambiguation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ft) (this is the second example in the above list).

Basically, what I am trying to illustrate here is that there is no off-the-shelf tool/library for this because resolving synonymy (especially colloquial terms, abbreviations, etc.) is a difficult problem.